# Map and iterator (in)validation

Tags: c++, dictionary, iterator, erase

I have a cache of items stored in a `map` that needs to be cleaned on occasion. `map::erase` invalidates the `curr` iterator, so I want to maintain a `next` pointer in case `curr` is deleted.

**Question:** if I `erase` the element at `curr`, does that invalidate `next`? I don't believe it does, but I want to be sure I'm not missing something obvious from [`map::erase`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/map/map/erase/)).

The code below also fails to compile with `error: no match for ‘operator+’ in ‘curr + 1’`:

```
typedef map<string, SSL_CTX_ptr> Contexts;
...

Contexts::const_iterator curr, next;

curr = contexts.begin();
while (curr != contexts.end())
{
    if(IsOkToRemove(curr))
    {
        next = curr + 1;
        contexts.erase(curr);
        curr = next;

        continue;
    }
    curr++;
}
```

**Question:** how do I set `next` to the element following `curr`?

**EDIT:** Kerrek's example below is the exact situation I was trying to understand:

```
contexts.erase(it++);
```

Within `erase`, the element is erased. That means the caller's iterator to the same element is invalidated before the post increment occurs. Because the iterator is invalidated, its the reason I'm trying to do `curr + 1` above. And its the reason I wanted to ensure `next` was always valid.

Comment: By reading the documentation.

Comment: Lightness Races in Orbi - what's the point of that comment?

Comment: As a side note: You should use `@<username>` (e.g. @noloader) to address particular users in comments (this will enable notification for them, even if they're not owner of the post, or first commenter).

Comment: @noloader: The point is to encourage you to read the documentation. Do you not think that might help you, doing that? I guarantee that it will.

Comment: Lightness Races in Orbit - I read the documentation (and even cited it). If the answer were that obvious, the discussion occurring on 
Kerrek's answer would not be happening. Perhaps you should keep your smart-ass comments to yourself to avoid melees.

Comment: "That means the caller's iterator to the same element is invalidated before the post increment occurs." -- why do you say that the iterator invalidation occurs *before* the post-increment? You are incorrect, it occurs after. Therefore, the value invalidated is no longer the value held in `it`.

Comment: "why do you say that the iterator invalidation occurs before the post-increment?" - because that is what the docs tell me. Deleting an element invalidates any iterators pointing to the element. Once the element is deleted you cannot do anything with it, including post increment it.

Answer (score 1):

Like this:

```
for (auto it = contexts.begin(); it != contexts.end(); )
{
    if (IsOkToRemove(it)) { contexts.erase(it++); }
    else                  { ++it;                 }
}
```

Since C++11 you can also say `it = contexts.erase(it);`, since `erase` was changed to return the iterator past the erased element in C++11.

Comment: Do you really want `++` here `contexts.erase(it++);`?

Comment: Kerrek - when I perform `erase` on `it`, doesn't that invalidate it so the `++` is undefined? That's why I'm trying to use `+ 1` (which won't compile).

Comment: `operator++` is certain to be a function call, therefore its side-effects are sequenced before it returns, hence are sequenced before the prior value is passed into `erase`. So no, `erase` does not invalidate `it`, because `it` no longer holds the value that is passed to `erase` and invalidated.

Comment: Thanks Steve. According to [map::erase](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/map/map/erase/), "Iterators, pointers and references referring to elements removed by the function are invalidated." So it does not matter if its a copy of an iterator. The element was removed, so all the iterators are invalid, including the copy in the caller. Am I reading it wrong?

Comment: @noloader: Please, use `@notification` syntax to address other users. After 3 years, you should really know this.

Comment: @noloader: The value of `it++` is the original value, but its side effect is to increment `it`. So all is fine.